# saving multiple data grid view value to database

Tags: c#

I have some rows in data grid view . I want to save them together in database..Please help me to do that. Thanks in Advance . I wrote the following but it doesn't work....!!!

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string StrQuery;
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    comm.Connection = myConnection;
                    myConnection.Open();
                    for (int i = 0; i < addcrsView.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO student_reg VALUES (" + id + ","
                            + addcrsView.Rows[i].Cells["Course Name"].Value + ", "
                            + addcrsView.Rows[i].Cells["Credit"].Value + ");";
                       comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                       if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("inserted");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("Not insert");
                       }

                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Catch");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You need to enclose your string column `CourseName` within single quotes.

**Solution 1:** I Don't Recommend this:

Try This:

```
StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO student_reg VALUES (" + id + ",'"
                        + addcrsView.Rows[i].Cells["Course Name"].Value + "', "
                        + addcrsView.Rows[i].Cells["Credit"].Value + ");";
```

Your query is open to *sql injection Attacks* i suggest you to use *Parameterised Queries* to avoid them.

**Solution 2:**

Using **Parameterised Queries:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < addcrsView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO student_reg VALUES (@id,@CourseName,@Credits)";
    comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName",addcrsView.Rows[i].
                          Cells["Course Name"].Value);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credits",addcrsView.Rows[i].
                          Cells["Credit"].Value);

    if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not insert");
    }
    comm.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

**Solution 3:** it is just a Suggestion:

You can only display the Success Message when only all records inserted Successfully.

Using **Parameterised Queries:**

```
int rowsCount = addcrsView.Rows.Count;
int rowsInserted = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
{
    StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO student_reg VALUES (@id,@CourseName,@Credits)";
    comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName",addcrsView.Rows[i].
                          Cells["Course Name"].Value);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credits",addcrsView.Rows[i].
                          Cells["Credit"].Value);

    if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        rowsInserted++;
    }
    comm.Parameters.Clear();
}//end of for loop


if(rowsCount == rowsInserted)
{
  MessageBox.Show("All Rows Inserted Successfully!");
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("All Rows Not Inserted Successfully!");
}
```

Comment: thanks to help, as i am beginner I dont think about SQL injection but thanks to advice to be careful..@Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: But it only save first row of gridview , I want all rows of gridview please help to ahead   .@Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @user3103779: Which solution you are using? `Solution1` or `Solution2`?

Comment: if it save only one record then check fist `addcrsView.Rows.Count` what it return .. ? coz the answer seems to perfect..

Comment: @user3103779: please check for `Solution3`.

Comment: It does not work , when I debug, it just doesnot execute the query.. on the following line.

Comment: @user3103779: which solution you are trying and which line does not work?

Comment: solution 3 @ Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @user3103779: which line is not working and what is the error message

Comment: the line is: if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) and even it doesn't work for one though it worked before.   pls help   @ Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @user3103779: it dos not show any messagebox for each record insertion , what is the error message you are getting

Comment: and yes it works nice... thanks a lot to be patient..:-) @ Sudhakar Tillapudi